# D* Lite and LPA* Algorithms: concept of predecessors and successors

Tags: algorithm, graph, path-finding, d-star

I am trying to implement the [D* Lite](http://idm-lab.org/bib/abstracts/papers/aaai02b.pdf) and [LPA*](http://idm-lab.org/bib/abstracts/papers/aij04.pdf) algorithms (both proposed by Sven Koenig), and I am having difficulty in understanding the concept of the list of predecessors and successors contained by each node. I tried looking for answers at various sources, but I couldn't find a definitive one.

Could anyone help me out with it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

On a directed graph:

- *successors* are those nodes that are reachable from the current node
- *predecessors* are those nodes from which the current node can be reached.

On an undirected graph (common for simple examples), they will be the same.

On the (undirected) 4-connected lattice below

- the *successors* of the node E are B, D, F and H (that is, if you're at E, you can reach any of the states pointed at by the arrows).
- the *predecessors* of the node E are B, D, F and H (found by flipping the directions of the arrows, and seeing what arrives at E).

[image: successor-nodes]